# Discover Kubernetes Service DNS Record

Tags: kubernetes

I work on a variety of different Kubernetes clusters in a variety of different clouds. My problem here is that it's difficult to discover what the FQDN for a kubernetes Service is as different clusters have different configurations.

Is there a way via `kubectl` to get the FQDN for a service? I don't see it when I use `kubectl describe svc`.

It should be something like `my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example` according to this article:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

How do I figure out the `cluster-domain.example` part of the FQDN? I could just go with `my-svc.my-namespace.svc` and have it resolve, but I'd like to use the FQDN if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subdomain is specified via flag `--cluster-domain` to `kubelet`, such that `kubelet` can use it as the search domain in the file `/etc/resolve.conf` of containers. When searching a Service name in a Pod, the FQDN is auto-completed by settings in the file `/etc/resolve.conf`.

For `kube-dns`, it includes 3 containers. One of them is named `kube-dns`, it has a flag `-domain` which has the same value as the cluster domain.

Comment: Thanks so much! I see it.

Answer (score 2):

The cluster domain is defined in configMap named `coredns` in `kube-system` namespace. This configMap is the source of truth and used by coreDNS.In the below Configmap cluster domain is `cluster.local`

```
kubectl get cm coredns -n kube-system -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health {
           lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           pods insecure
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
           ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-04-03T14:24:44Z"
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "177"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/coredns
  uid: d00d8e5d-d089-4d7a-a1d3-4460703c23d9
```

Comment: Oooh nice! What about on kube-dns clusters? I checked the config map for kube-dns but it doesn't have the address listed.

Comment: I am not sure about Kube-dns...I don't have a cluster which uses Kube-dns

Comment: there is a stubDomains in that Configmap?https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#coredns-configuration-equivalent-to-kube-dns